# How to remotely control of the screen of my Raspberry Pi 3 by PC?

Tags: pi-3, remote

I want to remote one or more Raspberry Pi 3 by my PC, and have my PC control my Raspberry to show something like a picture, open file, etc.

Who can help me?

Comment: It sounds like this: you want to control multiple Raspberry Pis at the same time. You want to show the same picture or open the same file on all the Raspberry Pis?

Comment: See https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/

Comment: thanks you, I want to remote my raspberry by terminal or python code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to run headless. Then you have to take two steps. First do raspi-config and activate the VNC 'option'. On your windows PC, you have to install a VNC client. I use VNC Viewer.

The rest is pretty striaght forward.

Comment: thanks you, can I control my raspberry by terminal or python code?

Answer (score 0):

To control your raspi with a terminal program you can use `ssh` (secure shell). First you have to put a file named `ssh` into the boot directory (it's the mounted boot partition). The file may be empty. You can do it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo touch /boot/ssh
```

Now reboot and you will have the ssh server enabled on your raspi so you can connect to it with a ssh client. First get the ip address on the raspi with:

```
rpi ~$ hostname -I | cut -d' ' -f1
```

For example you will find: `169.254.62.234`. If you use the initial setup on the raspi then you can connect from a linux pc with:

```
pc ~$ ssh pi@169.254.62.234
```

This will open a terminal connected to the raspi where you can control it. To connect from a Microsoft Windows PC you can use `putty`. Don't know how to configure it in detail. I don't use it.

Python is a programming language and usually not used to open a terminal on a remote machine. If you want you have to program it but it makes less sense because we have ssh for this. You can use Python to program specific tasks, for example down- and upload files or something else.